# Sharing files from windows

Tags: sharing

I use windows phone. I want to share files from it with my ubuntu laptop. How to do it?
I tried to connect it using bluetooth but bluetooth is also not getting connected. Moreover it will be pretty time consuming to share big files over bluetooth.

Comment: Does a USB cord not work?

Comment: Mine is windows phone. I don't know which drivers to install 1st.

Answer (score 2):

You can take two diferents ways.. use internet to transfer the files or use Samba.

Samba its an emulator of window's network.

The first step is to install the samba package. From a terminal prompt enter:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

The main Samba configuration file is located in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. The default configuration file has a significant amount of comments in order to document various configuration directives.

First, edit the following key/value pairs in the [global] section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
 workgroup = EXAMPLE
   ...
   security = user
```

The security parameter is farther down in the [global] section, and is commented by default. Also, change EXAMPLE to better match your environment.

Create a new section at the bottom of the file, or uncomment one of the examples, for the directory to be shared:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /srv/samba/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

*comment: a short description of the share. Adjust to fit your needs.*

*path: the path to the directory to share.*

*This example uses /srv/samba/sharename because, according to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS), /srv is where site-specific data should be served. Technically Samba shares can be placed anywhere on the filesystem as long as the permissions are correct, but adhering to standards is recommended.*

*browsable: enables Windows clients to browse the shared directory using Windows Explorer.*

*guest ok: allows clients to connect to the share without supplying a password.*

*read only: determines if the share is read only or if write privileges are granted. Write privileges are allowed only when the value is no, as is seen in this example. If the value is yes, then access to the share is read only.*

*create mask: determines the permissions new files will have when created.*

Now that Samba is configured, the directory needs to be created and the permissions changed. From a terminal enter:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/samba/share

sudo chown nobody:nogroup /srv/samba/share/
```

*The -p switch tells mkdir to create the entire directory tree if it doesn't exist.*

Finally, restart the samba services to enable the new configuration:

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

[Original Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for teach me, i han been edited the question, 
a greeting!

Comment: Its a read only file. I am unable to make the above changes.

Comment: What file is read only? Have you tried giving it administrator permissions before editing it?